# how do I remove duplicate values from a pandas pivot table?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So I am trying to reproduce a set of instructions for excel into python. The problem is I know very little about excel and what's happening.

I have a data frame:

```
no.    name    corrected no.    corrected name
001    alpha   001              alpha
002    beta    002              beta
002    beta2   002              beta
003    gamma   003              gamma
004    delta   104              delta
003    omega   003              gamma
...    ...     ...              ...
```

In excel the instructions say to create a pivot table with all those columns in the 'ROWS' section.

I've done this with both 'groupby' and 'pivot_table' in pandas

```
df.groupby(['no.', 'name', 'corrected name'])[['corrected no.']].mean()
or
pd.pivot_table(df[['no.', 'name', 'corrected name', 'corrected no.']], index=['no.', 'name'])
```

which looks like:

```
no.    name    corrected no.    corrected name
001    alpha   001              alpha
002    beta    002              beta
       beta2   002              beta
003    gamma   003              gamma
       omega   003              gamma
004    delta   104              delta
```

now I want to remove all the additional rows from groups with more than one name. e.g. in this case I would like to remove the 'beta2' & 'omega' rows;

something like this:

```
no.    name    corrected no.    corrected name
001    alpha   001              alpha
002    beta    002              beta
003    gamma   003              gamma
004    delta   104              delta
```

So there is only one 'name' per 'no.'
The problem is once I get the 'pivot table', it returns a table which can't be manipulated and is only 1 column.

Answer (score 1):

Works either way, but with the `groupby` result:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s{2,}')  # sample rows

s = df.groupby(['no.', 'name', 'corrected name'])[['corrected no.']].mean()

s
Out[27]: 
                          corrected no.
no. name  corrected name               
1   alpha alpha                       1
2   beta  beta                        2
    beta2 beta                        2
3   gamma gamma                       3
    omega gamma                       3
4   delta delta                     104

s.groupby(level=['no.', 'corrected name']).first()
Out[28]: 
                    corrected no.
no. corrected name               
1   alpha                       1
2   beta                        2
3   gamma                       3
4   delta                     104
```

Comment: thanks. I used the '.first()' but managed to do to it in the first line by switching the columns as such:

df.groupby(['no.', 'corrected name', 'corrected no.'])[[ 'name']].first()